# Motion framework - create repeating animation? (CosmicMind)

Tags: cosmicmind

Firstly, thank you for the great frameworks (Material and Motion) and generally awesome documentation.

I have been migrating to various Material and Motion classes in my app and enjoying it, but i have a situation I can't quite figure out an elegant way to handle with Motion.

I like to have a repeating background pulse animation that triggers on an IBAction and stops on an IBAction, but motion animations are 'one shot', and im not sure how to trigger a long running animation (unknown duration, repeating) and keep a handle on it, then stop it.

Is this a paradigm supported by Motion?

Thank you

Comment: Using a CAAnimation like so without Motion seems to do it:

`let backgroundAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "backgroundColor")
backgroundAnimation.fromValue = Color.red.base.cgColor
backgroundAnimation.toValue = Color.red.darken4.cgColor
backgroundAnimation.duration = 1.0
backgroundAnimation.repeatCount = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude;
backgroundAnimation.autoreverses = true`

Comment: Thank you! We have an issue for this, that will be completed once we get our next major releases out. https://github.com/CosmicMind/Motion/issues/13 Feel free to follow that for now, and I think making a custom animation that repeats is a great approach.